# Converting between STL stack and deque

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a way to convert a C++ STL deque to a stack, and vice versa, without iterating over each element of the source manually?  (I'm not sure if one of the `<cast>`s are usable here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stack` is just an container adaptor, so you can just pass `deque` object to it to use it as a container:

```
std::deque<int> my_deque;
// Do something with deque here
std::stack<int> s(my_deque);
```

To covert in other direction, you can use constructor with the iterators:

I am not sure if you can do the direct conversion vice-versa (other than using `my_deque` directly). Only thing that I can think of is following:

```
std::deque<int> other_deck;
// Construct new stack:
std::stack<int> new_stack(other_deck);
// use std::swap
std::swap(new_stack, old_stack);
```

Now the `other_deck` should be filled with the from the `old_stack`.

> Exchanges the contents of the container adaptor with those of other. Effectively calls `using std::swap; swap(c, other.c);`

**Edit** It seems that `swap` is just swapping the underlying containers, and not the container's contents, so this will not work.

Comment: I suppose any copy operation would iterate over the soruce anyway, so there won't be that much of a performance hit.  I assume there's not a way to get access to the `deque` inside of the source `stack`?

Comment: No, there's not, unfortunately, the interface of stack is available here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/.